# How to get default structure of spring boot web project in spring sts?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I have some ongoing spring boot web project in spring sts IDE. Then I create a new project which is reading the data from database using JSP file , for that I was created dynamic web project, in that time there was a pop message showing project need to change in JAVA EE format something like that. After clicking the ok button. It will change all of my previous projects structure. How to get rid of this problem.And want to know why this is happening?. Thanks in advance.

Project structure:
https://cdn.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/SpringBootApplication-Project.png

I have try to create new spring boot project to get the default structure , but its changes its project structure.

Want to get the previous project structure for all of my previous spring boot project and newly created project.Want to remove deployment descriptor/JAX-WS web Services and related file from the project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to spring sts -> window -> perspective -> other perspective -> other ->select spring(default). 
Change the **java EE perspective** to **Spring (default) perspective**.

https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-31.htm